# Cannot connect Admin SDK to firebase authentication emulator

Tags: firebase, firebase-admin

I am trying to connect the Admin SDK to the firebase authentication emulator. But for some reason , the Admin SDK keeps connecting to the live online project. The firebase authentication emulator is running though. I tried setting setting the FIREBASE_AUTH_EMULATOR_HOST environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS = key.json`and the project ID by`admin.initializeApp({ projectId: "YOUR_PROJECT_ID" };`. It didn't work. I tried [downloading the key from Google Cloud Console using a service account and setting the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable to point to that key](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator#set_up_admin_credentials_optional). But the admin SDK still uses the live project. How do I connect the admin SDK to the local firebase authentication emulator?

Comment: Please edit the question to show the code that isn't working the way you expect.

Comment: Hey, @Parth I'm running into a similar issue and am wondering if you found a solution? If not I'll create another question with code samples.

Comment: Nope still haven't found a solution. I had to use the live online firebase authentication service

Answer (score 0):

You can connect the admin SDK by setting an environment variable.

eg:
Using the command line:

```bash
export FIREBASE_AUTH_EMULATOR_HOST='localhost:9099'
```

Using node, you can also set this with:

```
process.env.FIREBASE_AUTH_EMULATOR_HOST='localhost:9099'
```

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you use the same process (terminal/cmd) to set the environment variable as you build and run your project with.

I Spring boot I simply add a line to my grade test script

```
tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    environment("FIREBASE_AUTH_EMULATOR_HOST", "localhost:9099")
}
```